# Merge or 'reference' and object into another through GraphQL?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, apollo

Very new to graphQL (and MongoDB), and I am wondering how to reference an another object in graph QL.

I have two objects in two collections in MongoDB...

```
{
    _id: 1,
    companies: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Google'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Apple'
        }
    ]
}

{
    _id: 2,
    jobs: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Designer'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Developer'
        }
    ]
}
```

The Designer job is posted by google, and I want to include that in the returned object from GraphQL (I am using the 'id: 1' as a reference I guess? Presume ObjectID might be the way to go instead tho )

How would I go about that?

Ideally I want to return

```
{
  "data": {
    "job": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Designer",
      "company": {
        id: 1,
        name: "Google"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

But not sure how to go about it, I currently have...

```
resolvers.js
  export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      jobs: async (_parent, {}, context) => {
        const jobs = await context.db
          .collection('jobs')
          .findOne()
          return jobs.jobs
      },
      companies: async (_parent, {}, context) => {
        const companies = await context.db
          .collection('companies')
          .findOne()
          return companies.companies
      },
      job: async (_parent, { id }, context) => {
        const job = await context.db.collection('jobs').findOne()
        return job.jobs.find((job) => job.id === Number(id))
      },
    },
  }

typeDefs.js

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Job {
    _id: ID
    id: Int
    title: String
  }
  type Company {
    _id: ID
    id: Int
    name: String
  }
  type Query {
      jobs: [Job]
      companies: [Company]
      job(id: Int): Job
  }
`
```

But not sure how to tie these in together? I am using Apollo / GraphQL / MongoDB / NextJS and essentially set up [very close to this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/setting-up-graphql-api-with-mongodb-and-apollo-server-for-a-nextjs-app-cec7a9baedbf)

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance!